# Extract untranslated strings from PO file

Tags: gettext, po

I would like to remove all translated strings from a PO file, or generate a PO file with only the untranslated strings.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found how:

```
 msgattrib --untranslated source.po -o output.po
```